# How to calculate the 90th percentile of a column corresponding to another column having same characters using R

Tags: r

```
df<-read. csv("input. csv") 
df
So my dataframe df looks like this... 
Name              Time
Launch              10
Launch              20
Launch              30
Login                 55
Login                 69     
Login                 48
Login                 74
Logout              29
Logout              13
```

Basically what I want is to add another column to my dataframe and it should hold 90th percentile of column"Time" wrt column "Name"

My expected output should look like..

```
Name              90thpercentile-_Time
Launch              90thpercentile(10,20,30)
Login                 90thpercentile(55,69,48,74)
Logout              90thpercentile(29,13)
```

I tried a lot using R by using functions like quantile,  aggregate but I did not get the expected result. 
Could someone help please???

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregate(df$Time, by=list(Name=df$Name), FUN=function(x) quantile(x, probs =0.9))
```

Comment: What is x here? Can u explain pls

Comment: Its your custom function. Usually you use sum, mean etc. functions alongside aggregate functionality, but you can take advantage to use whatever functions you want. In this case "x" is an argument of the function.

Comment: But in my case will x remain as argument or something?

Comment: I would say "x" here is your argument to quantile function taken from df$Time. So in general, your argument is df$Time.

Comment: Sweet. If the answer is usefull please accept it by upvoting.

Comment: Hey thanks it's working.. But can you help a little the result I get can I store that in to variable means

Comment: Output<-aggregate(df$Time, by=list(Name=df$Name), FUN=function(x) quantile(x, probs =0.9))... Will it work??                             Can you suggest anything

Comment: Please rephrase your question.

Comment: OK when I execute the code you gave.. It gave the result.. But I need to store the result in same  data frame name ie df .. So that I can write the result to a separate csv file. Can you help?

Comment: df$newvar=aggregate(df$Time, by=list(Name=df$Name), FUN=function(x) quantile(x, probs =0.9))